# set jsp element using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to set jsp variable value from document.getElementById

My HTML element is

```
<span id="noOfRecPerPage" style="display: none;">${pulseDetails.noOfRecPerpage}</span>
```

I want to set the value to  like below, but it is not working

```
<c:set var="noOfRecPerPage" value="${document.getElementById('noOfRecPerPage').innerHTML}"/>

<c:set var="noOfRecPerPage" value="<script>document.getElementById('noOfRecPerPage').innerHTML</script>"/>

<c:set var="noOfRecPerPage" value="document.getElementById('noOfRecPerPage').innerHTML"/>

<c:set var="noOfRecPerPage" value="<script>document.getElementById('noOfRecPerPage').value</script>"/>

<c:set var="noOfRecPerPage" value="${document.getElementById('noOfRecPerPage').value}"/>
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you still have trouble, please provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix EL (serverside code) and Jquery/Javascript (clientside).
As i explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41382210/1107653
You **can not use** `<c:set>` with value javascript code.

1. Expression Language is evaluated on the server, when compiling the JSP into Servlet.
2. The Servlet generate the response: html + javascript and send it back to the browser.
3. The Browser evaluate the Javascript.

**What you can do:**

**On the server side:**

You can use the content of the Element: `${pulseDetails.noOfRecPerpage}` directly:

```
<c:set var="noOfRecPerPage" value="${pulseDetails.noOfRecPerpage}">
```

Or make some javascript preparation:

```
<script>
    var noOfRecPerPage= "${pulseDetails.noOfRecPerpage}";
</script>
```

And use it directly in other Javascript code parts.

**Or On the client side:**

Just use **only** javascript to access the Element:

```
<script>
    var noOfRecPerPage = document.getElementById('noOfRecPerPage').innerHTML;
</script>
```