# Iterate hashmap stored in Model in javascript

Tags: javascript, el

While trying to iterate a map in a javascript function by passing ***key***  as below:

```
        <html> <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function demo(tmp){ 
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${usermap}"> 
    <c:out value="${usermap.get(\"+'tmp'+\").name}"></c:out>    
    </c:forEach>    
    } 
    </script> 
<title>Insert title here</title> </head>
 <body> 
<h1 onclick="demo('user1')">User VO</h1> 
<c:forEach var="user" items="${usermap}"> 
 Key: ${user.key}  - Name: ${user.value.name} - Id: ${user.value.userid}<br/><br/> 
</c:forEach> 
</body> </html>
```

I am getting blank value. But when I hard code the value of key***user1***, it works.

Servlet Code
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    //System.out.println("in servlet doGet:"+ ++count);
    UserVO user1= new UserVO("Y","701");
    UserVO user2= new UserVO("D","834");


    hmap.put("user1", user1);
    hmap.put("user2", user2);
    //hmap.values()
    request.setAttribute("usermap", hmap);
    //response.sendRedirect("User.jsp");
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("User.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}
```

Can somebody help me here?

Comment: This isn't clear at all. What's the "Model" you're talking about? Why is this question tagged [tag:el]?

Comment: Its a Model attribute..We have set the serviceProfile attribute in servlet as

Comment: model.addAttribute("serviceProfile", serviceProfile);

Comment: I think you should make clear what languages you're using (Java, I presume) and what's the context of those snippets. Are those generated server-side? How are you going to use `Cfs_id`?

Comment: I am using java. First the user is selecting the serviceId like Airtel-01 which is being passed to dummy method as argument. And I am checking the same serviceId in Map and send it further to another function in javascript. The issue I am facing is passing the serviceId to get method.                                                                                                var Cfs_id="${serviceProfile.serviceIdMap.get(serviceId).Id}";                   There is something wrong with the syntax while passing serviceId. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: You should update your post with those additional data.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: You have changed everything.  No one of the code related  comments/answer can be understand any more.

Comment: Please post the html code received in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

**The Issue:**

You are mixing client side and server side code. JavaScript and JavaServer Pages are executed separately.

- JSP code is compiled on the server,
- The result is a HTML, that is delivered to the browser
- In the browser the JavaScript is executed

So JSP related stuff like:

- JSTL, JSP Standard Tag Library (tags like `<jsp:something>` `<c:something>`)
- JSP-EL, Expression Language (strings like `${something}`)

is processed on the server.

You can see, what HTML code is received in browser, by pressing `Ctrl+U` in Firefox/Chrome.

**In your case:**

Selecting an option in the select-tag is executed on the client side in browser.
It is too late for EL-evaluation. The EL has bean already evaluated.
You can use ajax to request the needed data (map) according the user selection.

**EDIT**:

The EL of the hardcoded line is executed on the server and replaced with the value.  On the other case, when select-tag is involved, the EL was executed on the server and replaced by `var Cfs_id ="";`. So the dummy function ignore the parameter serviceId and set the variable always to empty string.

Look the code in your browser. There is only Html and Javascript. The JSP EL are no more there.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that.. But how come I am getting the value from the same map when I hard the code the value of  **serviceId**    i.e                        var Cfs_id="${serviceProfile.serviceIdMap.get("airtel").Id}".

Comment: I have updated the original  code. Added servlet and jsp code. After page is rendered, map is still there in request obj. The only issue is I am not able to get the key. Can you try and run this code.